# App to App authentication and authorization : Use keycloak instead of IS4

Tags: .net-core, single-sign-on, keycloak, identityserver4

In IdentityServer4, resources are defined and then the client is given the rights or not to access these resources. A resource can therefore be accessible by several clients. A client can also access several resources.

Resources has an clientId and clientSecret. this is used for OAuth2 Introspection.

I searched a lot and couldn't find how to do it in keycloak: Configure a clients, a resources and adding access role (negative by default).

Helps to implement it using keycloak. I need also an example using dotnet core code